# I do not understand recrusive methods

Tags: java, methods

```
    public static double calculatePower (double x, int y) {
        if (y == 0) 
           return 1;
        else 
           return (int) calculatePower(x, y-1);
```

I understand how the recrusive function is called, but not how it is cancelled.

I think, if at some point `y=1` the function should `return 1` because of the `if` statement.
But it does not and I do not understand why

Comment: There isn’t any more to it than you already said. I recommend you manually execute the function using a pen and a piece of paper, by keeping track of the current value of `x` and `y`, and evaluate, say, `calculatePower(5, 3)`.

Comment: This method will always return 1, except if `y` is too big (or too small) and causes a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: yea sorry i forgot the *x at the end of the return statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every recursive invocation the incoming `y` parameter is reduced by one since you write `calculatePower(x, y-1);`. At some point `y` is `0` and the recursion stops.

Note that your power calculation is wrong , you should add a `x *`  before the actual recursive call: `x * calculatePower(x, y-1)`

Comment: I'd like to highlight the second part of your answer. That bug in the OP code is the root cause of not understanding recursion

Comment: *"At some point `y` is `0` and the recursion stops."*
Well, about that... the assumption here is that `y` is a positive integer, but that is not enforced.
You may want to add this as a side note.

Answer (score 3):

This will subtract 1 from y every time it gets executed.

I recommend you execute it manually on paper to see how the program works.

ex: calculatepower(2,3) -> calculatepower(2,2) -> calculatepower(2,1) -> calculatepower(2,0). Now since y = 0 the if statement will get executed and it will return 1

Your function will only return the value 1 though (if y was a positive number)

This youtube tutorial will give you a clear explanation for recursion:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neuDuf_i8Sg

Comment: But where does Java store the value of return? 

implicitly you would use a variable x and multiply all values (with a while or for loop)
for ...{
x*=x 
}
return x; 

these values would be stored in x
but I don't understand the return.

Comment: try running the following code and see what happens

int x = calculatepower(2,3);

System.out.println(x);

Note: replace the code you have in else condition with the following : return (int)  x * calculatePower(x, y-1).